# Does the Chinese government give special treatment to ethnic minorities when it comes to general promotion and promotion into the Central Committee?

Tags: china

The Central Committee is composed of 205 members and 171 alternate members, 39 of which are ethnic minorities. I was wondering if the Chinese Communist Party was "fully" meritocratic or whether it gave special treatment to minorities making it easier for ethnic minorities to join the Central Committee. I heard that for college admission, ethnic minorities are given a special treatment making it easier for them to go to a top university than the Han majority. I was wondering if it was the same for the promotion of government officials to the Central Committee. Is this also true for general promotions?

Comment: You might wait a long time before a Tibetian or a Uyghur is "meritocratically" elected to lead the CCP

Comment: This article is interesting: it suggests representation varies a lot between minorities and is often used to secure the loyalty of minority leaders and groups.  https://macropolo.org/analysis/representation-19th-npc-central-committee-chinese-politics/